# Что такое йотово-посессивная топонимия?

Tags: словообразование, йотовый-суффикс, йот

Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучает топонимы, т.е. географические названия, происходящие от имён и фамилий.

Посессионные названия -те, кот. возникли из фамилий феодалов, чиновников, помещиков: Голицыно или Шереметево .

Йотовые - архаические, образованные с суффиксом -j-  усечённая модель -jь-

Например, Ярославль

Окончания могут быть разные: -а жен. р. (Пустопержа, Видогоща), -о, -е ср.
р. (Нудогощо, Воиславле),  формант -Ш (< -ь) муж. р.
(Всевижь, Домославль) или -и мн. ч. (Хотовижи, Гонежи).

Такие топонимы изменились, приняли другой вид, но их можно распознать:современная Людгоща < Людьгоща, - *Людьгость.

Деревня  Доброселье. Исконная форма − Доброславль – притяжательное образова-
ние от личн. Доброславъ, прасл. *Dobroslavъ, очень популярного имени

Comment: Про топонимию - поняла, посессивный - принадлежащий; я йота не вижу! Где йот в Ярославле - "-j- усечённая модель -jь-"?

Comment: Так Ярославль-то уже итог 1 палатализации, Губные согласные [m], [b], [p], [w] в позиции перед [j] развивали -л- как любить—люб[ьj]ю -  люблю, славить-славью -славлю.

Comment: Ярославль-Ярилу (солнце, весну) славлю